# What is the equivalent of <template *ngFor in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to do something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let parent of parents">
    <div *ngFor="let child of parent.children">
    </div>
</div>
```

but I don't want that extra outer div. From what i've been able to find searching, in Angular 1 I could achieve this by doing this:

```
<template *ngFor="let parent of parents">
    <div *ngFor="let child of parent.children">
    </div>
</template>
```

This doesn't seem to work in Angular 2 though. What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: See the Syntax section of https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think this should work for you:

```
<ng-template ngFor let-parent [ngForOf]="parents">
   <div *ngFor="let child of parent.children">
   </div>
</ng-template>
```

You can read more here:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#star-template

Also you can now use:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let parent of parents">
   <div *ngFor="let child of parent.children">
   </div>
</ng-container>
```

The advantage here is that it has the same syntax as with a normal dom element.

Comment: How do you get the index (`let i = index`) using the above syntax?

Comment: In Angular 4.x it's `ng-template`

Comment: HGB, to get the index you would just add the let-i="index" like this: <ng-template ngFor let-parent [ngForOf]="parents" let-i="index"></ng-template>

Answer (score 6):

And for index use `let-i="index"`:

```
<template ngFor let-hero [ngForOf]="heroes" let-i="index" let-odd="odd">
  <div [class.odd]="odd">({{i}}) {{hero.name}}</div>
</template>
```

More here:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#!#microsyntax

Answer (score 6):

`<ng-container>` behaves like a `<template>` tag (it is not added to the DOM) but allows to use the more convenient `*foo` structural directive syntax:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let parent of parents">
    <div *ngFor="let child of parent.children">
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

For more details about `NgFor` see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html